# sqlite3 interpreting a single bound string as multiple bindings

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table created like this:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE program_types (program_type_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, program_type TEXT);")
```

I populate it like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO program_types VALUES(NULL, ?);", ("blah"))
```

And it gives me this error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

If I switch the number of characters, as in:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO program_types VALUES(NULL, ?);", ("blahblah"))
```

The number of bindings sql finds increases to match the number of characters in the bound string:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change it to ```("blah",)```.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!